# How to detect "delete" or "edit" events in popup menu created with Leaflet-draw-toolbar plugin?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gis, toolbar, leaflet.draw

In [this example](https://justinmanley.github.io/leaflet-draw-toolbar/examples/popup.html) you may create a polygon and then click it and popup menu shows. There is three buttons: edit, delete and pick a color. How can I detect event and determine which of it - delete or edit - was executed in popup menu? I want to perform some action when one of this events is executed e.g. when a polygon is edited or deleted. The standart way for it:

```
map.on('draw:created', function (evt) {
        layer = evt.layer;
        // do something when polygon is created
});

map.on('draw:edited', function (evt) {
        layer = evt.layer;
        // do something when polygon is edited
});

map.on('draw:deleted', function (evt) {
        layer = evt.layer;
        // do something when polygon is deleted
});
```

But for events in popup menu it doesn't work.

So I edited file `leaflet.draw-toolbar.js` and added my custom event `'draw-popup:edited'`

```
LeafletToolbar.EditAction.Popup.Edit = LeafletToolbar.ToolbarAction.extend({
...
    map.on('click', function () {
        shape.editing.disable();
        shape.fire('draw-popup:edited', shape);
    });
...
});
```

Now in my script file I'm able to detect `'draw-popup:edited'` event

```
layer.on('draw-popup:edited', function() {
        var geom = this.toGeoJSON();
        console.log(geom);

});
```

But now it's fired multiple times when I click on a map and returns all shapes that were edited.
What is the right way to detect event and return the shape that was edited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug. The developer fixed it. More detail on [github.com](https://github.com/justinmanley/leaflet-draw-toolbar/issues/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
$('#map').on('click', '.leaflet-popup-toolbar', () => {console.log('click')})
```

Comment: thanks for reply. Your code just detects click event on popup menu. But I want to know which action - delete or edit - was executed and which polygon was deleted or edited. I corrected the question.